# discord.pyによるデータの保存

Tags: python, python3, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
from datetime import datetime
from discord.utils import find
import traceback 
import requests
import json
import urllib.request
import asyncio   

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, command_prefix):
        super().__init__(command_prefix)
        for cog in INITIAL_COGS:
            try:
                self.load_extension(cog)
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()

            async def on_ready(self):
                while True:
                    if #レポートに変更があったら:
                        embed = discord.Embed(title="NHK緊急地震速報", description='', color=0xff0000)
                        embed.add_field(name="発生時間", value=replay, inline=True)
                        embed.add_field(name="深央", value=sinnou, inline=True)
                        embed.add_field(name="深さ", value=hukasa, inline=True)
                        embed.add_field(name="強さ(M)", value=mg, inline=True)
                        embed.add_field(name="最大震度", value="震度" + sindo, inline=True)
                        embed.add_field(name="最大震度" + sindo + "を観測した地域", value=location, inline=True)
                        channel = self.get_channel(549218559792906268)
                        await channel.send(embed=embed)
                    eqreport = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www3.nhk.or.jp/sokuho/jishin/data/JishinReport.xml').read()
                    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

このように一定時間に一回のコードの入手のやり方は分かるのですが、それをどのように保存すればいいのかとそのレポートとサイトを比べて変化があった場合を調べる方法が分かりません。

ご教授お願い致します。

Comment: 関連質問です: ["How do I watch a file for changes?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/182197/5989200)

Comment: 関連ソフトウェアです: https://github.com/thp/urlwatch

Comment: なるほど・・・
がんばってみます